# beat up or beaten up

Tags: grammaticality

Without an audience Gandhi would have just  been some guy who goes around getting beat up a lot ?

My question is : Is 'beat up' grammatically sound or it should have been 'beaten up' and WHY?

Thank You.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=getting+beat+up%2Cgetting+beaten+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgetting%20beat%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgetting%20beaten%20up%3B%2Cc0

Comment: To 'go around getting beat/en up a lot' is a questionable expression, both conceptually and grammatically.

Answer (score 1):

Beat up is an idiomatic expression requiring both words in the phrase. Otherwise, beat would mean bested in a contest of rivals. Beaten is the past participle of to beat. An example might be, "The opposing team was soundly beaten." The past participle can also be used as a gerund, which behaves like an adjective: "Add 4 beaten eggs to the mix."

It might be a good idea to avoid using the phrase "a lot" immediately after the idiom "beat up," both being slang idiomatic expressions. For example, you could say that Gandhi was often beat up (or beaten) by thugs in the period immediately prior to Independence.

Comment: "Beat up", used as a past participle, is American slang. You very rarely hear it used like that in Britain where most people would say "beaten up" - unless it were spoken in perhaps a Caribbean street register.

Answer (score 0):

"Beat-up" is an idiom that means "in bad condition". It does not necessarily have anything to do with getting beaten. A person might be beat-up because of excessive stress or hard work - no violence involved.

Once you think of "beat-up" as a state, rather than an action, it should be obvious that "going around getting beat-up" is not a meaningful construct.

If you want to insist on the physical violence, you would use "going around getting beaten up" (no hyphen).

Comment: ":beat up" also means "to suffer violence" and in US usage may be more common for this meaning than "beaten up". In this sense it is an idiom.